Opening .mdf file without ldf in Visual Studio 2022
I am trying to open a .mdf file using Visual Studio 2022 and create a database in local machine.
I ran the following query in Visual Studio
CREATE DATABASE MKT2024
    ON (FILENAME = N'C:\Users\b123\OneDrive - Test\Desktop\MKT_EDM.mdf')
    FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG
    GO

I get the following error:

Msg 1853, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The logical database file 'MKT_EDM_log' cannot be found. Specify the full path for the file.
Msg 1813, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Could not open new database 'MKT2024'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.

Is there a way to open the .mdf without the ldf file as this is not provided?
I don't have administrator rights as this is work machine.
Appreciate your guidance.
Thank you.

What is the default database file location https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/view-or-change-the-default-locations-for-data-and-log-files?view=sql-server-ver16 and does the instance have access to it? Note that ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG is ill-advised unless you have no other choice: MDF files are not backups, and need the log files to restore cleanly. You may get corrupted/missing data,

default file location is C:\Users\b123. How do i check if the instance have access to it? The .mdf file is provided by our customer and it does not come with any .ldf file.

Can you create a normal new database in that location? Is the instance a LocalDB, otherwise why would you use such a strange location?

Yes i can create a blank database. It is a LocalDB.

is there a way to open .mdf and create a database without .ldf file?

FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG should have worked, not sure why it's still erroring.

okay.. another question related to this. I can use SSMS to run the query above on machines where i have admin rights. But I now need to run this in work machine where admin rights is not granted. is there any setting in local SQL server instance to allow access to local folder where the mdf files are saved?

You'd need to be logged in as b123 for this to work. Or put the files in C:\Users\Public if you don't care of the risk.

I am already logged in as b123 but SSMS returns access denied..

Please try below commands to work with .mdf
EXEC sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname = 'MKT2024', 
                              @physname = 'C:\Path\To\MKT_EDM.mdf';

if above command doesn't work then try this:
CREATE DATABASE MKT2024
ON (FILENAME = 'C:\Path\To\MKT_EDM.mdf')
LOG ON (NAME = 'MKT_EDM_log', FILENAME = 'C:\Path\To\NewLog.ldf')
FOR ATTACH;

This command creates the new log file on the specified path.
Make sure you have rights to access mdf file. To allow rights follow the below steps:

Right-click the .mdf file. select Properties.

Inside Security tab click Edit and then Add to include the SQL Server service account.

Grant Read, Write, and Modify permissions.



Thank you but i do not have admin rights on this machine to allow the rights. I guess i have to use the suggestion above to place the file in C:\Users\Public and remove after i finish
